# Form submit not firing

Tags: forms

For some reason I am unable to get into my form_submit function. I have attempted to add a custom handler to the #submit to force the form to submit to it however I haven't gotten any where. Any advice on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

```
function cheo_whiteboard_admin_form(){

 if(user_access('administer')){
   $form['admin_menu'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t( 'Admin Menu' ),      
   );
$form['admin_menu']['admin_menu_archive'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Archive Search',
  // '#submit' => array('cheo_whiteboard_admin_form_submit'),
);    

$form['admin_menu']['search_date'] = array(
  '#type' =>'date_popup',

);

$form['admin_menu']['special_instructions'] = array(
  '#title' => 'Special Instructions:',
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#size' => 75,
);
$form['admin_menu']['staffing_officer'] = array(
  '#title' => 'Staffing Office Status:',
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#size' => 75,
);

 $form['#submit'][]='cheo_whiteboard_admin_form_submit';

return $form;
}



  function cheo_whiteboard_admin_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    dpm($form);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking for user access within the form builder function. Make sure that control is going to the actual form by adding a dpm. It is better to check permissions at the menu definition level unless you have a better reason not to do so.

Next try `$form['#submit']='cheo_whiteboard_admin_form_submit';`

This makes sure that `cheo_whiteboard_admin_form_submit` is the only form handler function and hence easier for you to debug.